# Make Fancybox Revolving

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I currently have a Fancybox gallery working well and I would like to make it revolving.

Right now if you scroll all the way to the end of the gallery, the gallery stops and you have to scroll back the other way.

How can I make it so that after I click "right" until I hit the end of the gallery that I can continue to click "right" to go back to the first image in the gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if using v1.3.4 set `cyclic` to `true` in your custom initialization script

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    cyclic : true
});
```

if using v2.x set `loop` to `true`

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    loop : true
});
```